# Https requirement in Openiddict using ARR

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, arr, openiddict

I'm using ARR without `https` offloading on our non-local hosting environments. That means requests that hit ARR are `https` but requests sent to the backend servers are just `http`.

If I disable `https` requirement in openiddict then configuration returns `http` urls. If I enable it then requests are refused bc the backend servers receive them as `http`. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you describe is actually a very common issue that impacts any ASP.NET Core application that does - or does not - use OpenIddict and appears when doing TLS termination at the reverse proxy level: in this case, ASP.NET Core has indeed no way to know what the actual scheme was, so it assumes `HttpRequest.Scheme` is `http`, not `https`.

To fix that, you'll have to restore the real scheme, so that all the middleware that depend on it - including OpenIddict - work as intended.

This can be done using the ["forwarded headers" middleware](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Middleware/HttpOverrides/src/ForwardedHeadersMiddleware.cs) by referencing the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides` package and calling `app.UseForwardedHeaders()`.

Depending on your proxy, you might need to tweak the settings to match the headers it uses.

Note: this middleware is automatically registered when using the IIS integration package. You can amend the default options using this syntax:

```
services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
});
```

---

If this approach doesn't work, you can still override the scheme using an inline middleware:

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    context.Request.Scheme = "https";

    return next();
});
```

Make sure you register it before any other middleware.

Comment: Because `ForwardedHeaderOptions.RequireSymmetry` is true by default, the default options wouldn't work behind ARR because `X-Forwarded-For` has 2 entries but `X-Forwarded-Proto` has 1. So setting `options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto` worked. Thanks. I used

    app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions()
            {
                ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto,
                
            });

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: `context.Request.Scheme = "https";` worked